# Current road's speed limit

Tags: ios, maps

Is it possible to get the current speed limit of a road? I’m not sure if this would be done using the ‘Maps' app as I don’t think its holds speed limit data.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you building a Map app or are you using the native Maps? Your question is a bit vague, and as far as i know you can't get the speed limit i think

Comment: I’m not sure what I would be using, thats the problem. All I really need to do is find the current speed limit for a road and store it as a NSString or whatever. All the other stuff I am capable of doing.

Comment: Well for what you are saying, you are building a Maps app! Don't really know btw how to get the speed limit, maybe Google it or go there personally! :D

Comment: There is a similar question here that was closed but still has a lot of good details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469101/how-to-get-the-marked-speed-limit-of-a-road-out-of-longitude-and-latitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the marked speed limit of a road, out of longitude and latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469101/how-to-get-the-marked-speed-limit-of-a-road-out-of-longitude-and-latitude)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functionality in MapKit for retrieving speed limits.

You may be able to get it by querying Google directly, or by querying some other third-party speed-limit database.  However, it's probably unlikely that you'd find a service offering that kind of data for free.

Figure out where from where you going to get the data and then someone can likely help with how you'd retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an open data project that might be of help to you as well as many others:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikispeedia