# Is there any google API that gives speed limit of streets in map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I want to develop an iPhone app, that will enable user to track his speed and speed limit of street/road. Is there any google map API that gives us this information? if not, can anybody tell me any alternate 3rd party solution.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such an API exists at the moment.

Comment: But there are some Apps in Apple appstore with this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Now google has started providing optional speed limit data.

See Roads Web Service section at following link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Answer (score 0):

Google *does* now provide a Roads API, in which you can query Speed Limit data, but, according to the page found here https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing, you must acquire a Google Maps For Work License. You may not query the speed limit data for free. It looks like the Business License runs $10k per year.