# How to get speed limit by using google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the speed limit of a specific route.
Is it possible to get by using any Google APIs ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469101/how-to-get-the-marked-speed-limit-of-a-road-out-of-longitude-and-latitude

see the above link friend some ideas are there.

Comment: This is a really old question but I thought I would add that the roads api can give you speed limits. 

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/

Comment: @JessonAtherton is right. But just wanna add that Google allows using the Roads API only on its PREMIUM PLAN :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get it for free by using their test API app. You can edit the GPS points in the GUI or add them to the list like below.

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/full/inspector_with_api_key/#33.804563,%20-118.390564|33.806534,%20-118.389818|33.808062,%20-118.388568|33.810220,%20-118.387004|33.811542,%20-118.386693|33.814829,%20-118.386496|33.815859,%20-118.385744|33.817249,%20-118.384425|33.818196,%20-118.383715

Answer (score 0):

Luckily now Google provides speed limit, by using their [Google Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) but only on their Premium Pricing Plan.