# Android GoogleMaps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a question concerning the android google maps API v2. I want to know if it is possible to get the route speed limit. An example:

I am on the route XY, this route has in the real life a maximum speed of 50km/h. I am driving 60km/h on this route XY. Now I want to give the user a signal -> Hey, stop driving so fast you aren't in the game GTA ;) as example :P

How can I get this 50km/h?

Comment: Maps V2 does not have routes, let alone speed limits regarding routes.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469101/how-to-get-the-marked-speed-limit-of-a-road-out-of-longitude-and-latitude