# How to get max allowed speed in user current road?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing-maps, here-api

In my windows phone 8 app, I need to know the max speed limit allowed on the current user road. Is there is an api to get this information?

Comment: Could be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8469101/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HERE Api states that it is available.

Under the [Need A Custom Solution](https://developer.here.com/get-started#/)?

and the Mobile SDK under [Guidance - Dynamic Information](https://developer.here.com/native-apis)